# A holomorphic $L_2$ function on the ring $\{r<z<R\}$.

Tags: complex-analysis

How do I prove that holomorphic $L_2$ function on the ring $\{r<z<R\}$ has orthogonal basis: $\phi_n (z)=z^n, n\in\mathbb{Z}$? Thanks.

Comment: Please show your working so far :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Hints** For orthogonality, just compute $\iint_\Omega \phi_n(z) \overline{\phi_m(z)}\,dA(z)$, where $\Omega$ is your annulus. Polar coordinates seems like the easiest approach. For completeness, think about Laurent series.